# Multiple If Statements for leap year logic, how to structure them?

Tags: java, if-statement

So in this code, I am trying to have the user enter in a year and a month (first 3 letters) and then determine how many days that specific month contains. Because of the difficulty involving leap years, I am having trouble with coding the part where the user enters "Feb" as a month. When I tested it, it said:
"Feb 2002 has 29 days"
"Feb 2002 has 28 days"

How do I make it so that it shows only 29 days?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a year: ");
    int year= input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter a month (first 3 letters with the first letter in uppercase): ");
    String month = input.nextLine();

    // leap year logic starts here
    if (year % 4 == 0 || "Feb".equals(month)) {
        System.out.println( month + year + "has 29 days");
    }
    else if (year % 4 > 0 || "Feb".equals(month)) {
        System.out.println( month + year + "has 28 days");
    }
    else if("Jan".equals(month) || "Mar".equals(month) ||
            "May".equals(month) || "July".equals(month) ||
            "Aug".equals(month) || "Oct".equals(month) ||
            "Dec".equals(month)) {
        System.out.println(month + year + "has 31 days");
    }
    else if ("Apr".equals(month)|| "Jun".equals(month) ||
             "Sep".equals(month) || "Nov".equals(month)) {
        System.out.println(month + year + "has 30 days");
    }
```

Comment: Didn't Feb 2002 only have 28 days?

Comment: Exactly, i need to make it so that it doesn't say that.

Comment: Danger: every 100 years is no leap year, but every 400 years is one.

Comment: For all you non-voters, I want you to know... This is actually a very important question to just about every new java coder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a simple logic flaw in your conditional statements.  Your ORs should be ANDs

```
if (year % 4 == 0 && "Feb".equals(month)){
    // Note the && above
    System.out.println( month + year + "has 29 days");
}
else if (year % 4 > 0 && "Feb".equals(month)){
    // Note the && above
    System.out.println( month + year + "has 28 days");
}
```

Each of your conditionals was (A || B).  The first condition, year%4==0 was evaluating to true and thus the 2nd condition was not even evaluated (This is called boolean-short-circuting).

Answer (score 0):

Besides using "and" (`&&`) you also need to nest them for the various conditions which make up a leap year:

```
boolean feb = "Feb".equals(month);
if (feb) {
    if (year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0))
    { System.out.println("has 29 days"); }
    else { System.out.println("has 28 days"); }
} else if (....) { }
```

I would however use a numerical month with a switch:

```
// NB: if you use Date.getMonth() add +1
switch(month) {
  case 1,3,5,7,9,10,12:
    System.out.println("31 days");
    break;
  case 4,6,7,11:
    System.out.println("30 days");
    break;
  case 2:
    if (year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0)) {
      System.out.println("has 29 days");
    } else {
      System.out.println("has 28 days");
    }
    break;
  }
```

But of course the best leap-year function is the one which you do not program yourself. Better check out system libraries: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/Getthelastdayofamonth.htm

Comment: I would also use `month = input.nextLine().toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);` and then you can use "jan", "feb", "mar" as the strings to compare as it does not matter if or if not the user uses uppercase. and you can use a final `else { System.out.println("Unknown Month " + month); }`

Comment: Thank you for the advice! Unfortunately, the assignment that I am doing requires it to be in capital letters.